# Is there any alternative way to simulate a continuous time model instead of discrete?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, control-theory, simulation

Normally I use the exponential matrix method to turn continuous time model to discrete time model. In this case, it's SS-models:

$$\dot x = Ax + Bu + Eu \\ y = Cx + Du$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
A_d & B_d &E_d \\ 
0 &I  &I 
\end{bmatrix} = e^{\begin{bmatrix}
A & B & E\\ 
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}}T_s$$

Where $T_s$ is the sampling time.

But I have a problem with it comes to this and it's because of the simulation of nonlinear systems.

If I have a nonlinear model:

$$\dot x = f(x, u)$$

And I want to linearize it in the state $x_0 = 0$. I know that it will be nothing left of the dynamics. Assume that we linearize at the initial state and we have some damping in our system, then the damping factor is going to be zero.

I going to do nonlinear numerical simulation of a discrete system. So my procedure is going to be:

1. Linearize the system in state $x$. E.g If we have the damping $Bx_2^2$ the it would be linearized to $2Bx_2$.
2. Turn it to discrete
3. Do the simulation and find state $x$
4. Jump to stage 1.

A lot of times, my simulation breaks. To do a simulation, I need to linearize the system first and then turn it to a discrete form, as I have been learned.

**Question:**

Is there any simpler way to simulate a nonlinear continuous time model?
Is there an alternative way to turn the model to discrete?

Nonlinear simulation seems to be so sensitive to against everything.

**EDIT:**

Here is the code. Assume that you know A, B and sample time h.

```
% Compute sizes
a1 = size(A,2) + size(B,2) - size(A,1);
b1 = size(A,2);
a2 = size(A,2) + size(B,2) - size(B,1);
b2 = size(B,2);
% Compute square matrix
M = [A B; zeros(a1, b1)  zeros(a2, b2)];
M = expm(M*h);
% Find the discrete matrecies
Ad = M(1:size(A,1), 1:size(A,2));
Bd = M(1:size(B,1), (size(A,2) + 1):(size(A,2) + size(B,2)));
```

Comment: What is the exponential of a non-square matrix?

Comment: It contains the state space matrices. @A.Γ.

Comment: The non-square matrix is a square matrix.

Comment: @A.Γ. I have uploaded some code.

Comment: `c2d` command with `zoh` method does this for you for linear systems. For nonlinear systems either use Simulink or form and solve the differential equations yourself without linearizing them.

Comment: @percusse I want to use pure MATLAB code for nonlinear simulation. Can I not keep the nonlinear model as it is and still do a simulation of it?

Comment: Pure matlab means constructing the nonlinear equation set and calling the right DE solver.

Comment: Do you means that the exponential calculation is wasting your simulation time?

Comment: @Arash Not wasting my time. But I try to build a basic nonlinear model predicitive control by first linearize the model and turn it to discrete shape and then turn the model to an augmented model and then use QP-programming to find the best input signals. Repeat. But I haveing some stability issues. If i set the initial linearizing vector to 0 and linearize in the origo point (0,0), then the exponential calucaltion won't work for me beacuse is something with the eigenvalues expm() function complaning about.

Comment: @Arash I assume that NMPC works that way. Or is it a better way to create a basic NMPC?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson, I call your method adaptive MPC rather than NMPC. Typically, NMPC uses [Nonlinear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_programming) method. If you use simulink it saves you a lot of time. If you use pure code, consider using [fmincon](https://au.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html).

Comment: @Arash Thank you for the information. But I still need to compute the augmented SS-model for nonlinear MPC? Do you recommend a system identification method/algorithm for Adaptive MPC?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson, I prefer passing this question to the other people who are more expert than me. But if I had to manage an ad-hoc  solution, I would consider control inputs as states and their increment as the input to be optimized. Regarding adaptive MPC I still did not understand why linearization did not work for you. Is it unstable at the origin?

Comment: @Arash is was something with the eigenvalues error from the expm() command. But I will try to find another way to simulate nonlinear system, without linearizing them.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson, I have a dirty idea but it probably works. Use Euler discretization. or see the section Approximations at [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization#Approximations).